# Is it better to write maximum code in .html file rather than in .ts file in angular 4?

Tags: angular

There are four flags in my code of which I am changing status on click.
for example, there are four buttons b1, b2, b3, b4 and four flags f1, f2, f3, f4. On click of b1, `f1=true` and rest other are false, similarly for other buttons.

I am setting this flags on click event itself as `(click)="f1=true;f2=false;f3=false;f4=false;"`. Should I write separate method as `(click) = "changeFlag();"` and on .ts I should change flag?

Comment: write separate method for this, in html file should have minimum code of js because when we want to debug at that time separate code we can easily debug

Comment: debugging html is tough once it gets big enough

Comment: as you are new : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write method , in you `ts` file that makes is more testable and manageable code. It good if you separate your code in ts file from html. that is more maintainable and readable also.

One more problem is testing code written in Html, if you have code in html and doing wrong then its very difficult to figure out , its why its should go in ts file , so its become maintainable.

its always good to follow this principle : [**Separation of concerns**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)-  is a design principle for separating a computer program into distinct sections, such that each section addresses a separate concern.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should definitely write a method in .ts class.

You can pass a number to your function and make a switch inside your function to apply changes to your flags.